# Linux Libertine O bold font combines characters

Tags: fonts, xetex

I'm typing Turkish text using Linux Libertine O boldface.

Everything is OK in FreeSerif and Libertine non bold fonts, but it's messed up in Libertine when using `\textbf`.

It seems similar to 
[Problem with character placement (XeLaTeX, Linux Libertine and Unicode)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118097/problem-with-character-placement-xelatex-linux-libertine-and-unicode)

Can somebody confirm if this is similar or that I am doing something wrong.
Here is a MWE.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8

\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{FreeSerif}
freeserif

n’ n' m’ m' sanʼatlarımızda çinʼde sanʼatı

\textbf{textbf n’ n' m’ m' sanʼatlarımızda çinʼde sanʼatı}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}
Linux Libertine O

n’ n' m’ m' sanʼatlarımızda çinʼde sanʼatı

\textbf{textbf n’ n' m’ m' sanʼatlarımızda çinʼde sanʼatı}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems a bug in the Libertine Semibold font, because in the other variants the result is always `nʼ`. Are you sure that U+02BC (MODIFIER LETTER APOSTROPHE) is the right character to use? If I google for `sanʼatlarımızda` I get no hit other than this question, while `san’atlarımızda` (with an apostrophe) finds something.

Comment: I used both type of quotes just to show (see for myself) if it would make a difference. Herbert's solution below solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,
             BoldFont=LinLibertineOB]{Linux Libertine O}
```

to get the bold libertine. Or in the preamble `\usepackage{libertine}` if you want it documentwide.